# How to use basic auth for single file in otherwise forbidden Apache directory?

Tags: security, apache-2.2, virtualhost, http-authentication

I want to allow access to a single file in a directory that is otherwise forbidden.

This did not work:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80>
  ServerName example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  # disallow the admin directory: 
  <Directory /var/www/html/admin>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
  </Directory>

  # but allow this single file:: 
  <Files      /var/www/html/admin/allowed.php>
      AuthType basic
      AuthName "private area"
      AuthUserFile /home/webroot/.htusers
      Require user admin1
  </Files>

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `http://example.com/admin/allowed.php` I get the  Forbidden message of the `http://example.com/admin/` directory, but not the browser login popup from the basic auth, so the basic auth does not work on the file. How can I make an exception for allowed.php?

If not possible, maybe I could enumerate all forbidden files in another Files directive?

Let's say admin/ contains also user.php and admin.php which should be forbidden in this virtual host.

*Edit:* I also tried the following modification, trying to follow advice from Ignacio's answer, with the same result 'Forbidden':

```
  ...

  # disallow the admin directory: 
  <Directory /var/www/html/admin>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
  </Directory>

  # but allow this single file:: 
  <Files      /var/www/html/admin/allowed.php>
      order allow,deny
      allow from all
      AuthType basic
      AuthName "private area"
      AuthUserFile /home/webroot/.htusers
      Require user admin1
      satisfy all
  </Files>
  ...
```

Comment: The `<Files ...>` reference only takes a filename, not a path, btw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/admin>
  <Files allowed.php>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "private area"
    AuthUserFile /home/webroot/.htusers
    Require user admin1
  </Files>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Files nested inside a Directory will only apply therein so your code block is more logically organized, and I think using the 'Satisfy any' will allow them to be merged as planned. I'm not sure if it's actually required so try it with and without the satisfy line...

Comment: Just want to confirm that this does work - I hope that mit will return and select this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the solution with `<Files xxx>` actually works well, as the [Require doc page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require) states that it doesn't apply to `Files`

```
Context:    directory, .htaccess
```

Instead what the apache doc suggests is to create a separate directory for the file:

> Removing controls in subdirectories
>
> The following example shows how to use the Satisfy directive to
>   disable access controls in a subdirectory of a protected directory.
>   This technique should be used with caution, because it will also
>   disable any access controls imposed by mod_authz_host.

```
<Directory /path/to/protected/>
    Require user david
</Directory>
<Directory /path/to/protected/unprotected>
    # All access controls and authentication are disabled
    # in this directory
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```